# C# Querying a datatable

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I have data in excel and I have transformed it into a datatable so that I can use it to query with sql statements. But querying datatable in c-sharp is not straightforward. Can anyone suggest a way to temporary read data from excel file hold it in memory, ask some queries hold results in datagridview and delete data from memory.

Comment: I think Connecting to DB and querying it is faster (In implementation), much efficient, and won't be a temp solution. It does worth the effort.

Comment: @MokhtarAshour I don't have sql.

Comment: no sql = no sql statement. you can try linq which is the closest you can get

Comment: @Steve is linq a datatable?

Comment: [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx)

Comment: check if you have LocalDB installed, run "sqllocaldb info"

Comment: Is sql or linq is more flexible  for queries?

Comment: @MokhtarAshour unfortunately not :-(

Comment: Ok, LINQ will help you query the data in memory or from DB, it's a querying language, and I recommend using it.

Comment: I suggest you install SQL Server Express and put your data there, this will require some effort, but it's efficient and you can migrate your data to other DBs later

Comment: @MokhtarAshour should I use datatable for query using linq. If yes, how?

Comment: once you have your DB ready, you can use LinqToSql to query your data using LINQ. although it's not the newest way to do that, but it's easy and will integrate well with your code

Comment: @MokhtarAshour thanks  for guidance. I think I need to go for Sql for best results.

Comment: What kind of database did you export the Excel to? Is it an SQL Database or an Access Database?

You should search for some tutorials on integrating / accessing a database from your visual studio project - as this is fundamental to most development.

Answer (score 1):

You can query against the rows in a DataTable by using Linq.

This can be found using a Google search for examples.

**What is Linq?**

Linq was/is developed by Microsoft as a programming model that gives you the ability to perform queries within the .net. Linq can also be used on multiple sources, such as DataTables, SQL Databases, arrays and more. The great thing about Linq is that it uses SQL-like syntax to make it understandable for Database Developers and Software Developers. However, do note that it is not as powerful as SQL due to only supporting less advanced techniques, however you can find out more about this when researching.

**Linq Example**

This example of Linq queries an array called words where the word length is = 3 and returns them.

```
from word in words where word.length == 3 select word;
```